# Android Call Activity by Intent from dialog then return to the dialog with result

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, adapter

After many search I can not resolve my problem. 
I start a dialog from adapter then from my dialog i call an activity (by intent). I would like to return to my dialog with the result from my activity. here my code :

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.context);
    dialog_actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            add_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {Intent add = new Intent(MyActivity.context,MySecondActivity.class);
                    MyActivity.context.startActivity(add);
```

From the called activity I would like to return to the dialog. How can i do ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: This would be simpler if, instead of a `Dialog`, you used a dialog-themed `Activity`.

Comment: What do you mean by dialog-themed Activity ? I don't know to use this.

Comment: I mean an activity whose theme extends from a dialog-based theme (e.g., `Theme.Material.Dialog`). Visually, it appears like a dialog. However, from a programming standpoint, it is an `Activity`, and so things like `startActivityForResult()` work normally.

Comment: Thanks but it is not what i want. I have a custom Dialog I would like to keep it. Is there a more adapted answer ?

Comment: Finally I have called a dialog-themed in my custom dialog. It's working fine. Thank you CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing your dialog from your adapter you can show it from an activity like below:

In your adapter:

```
((YourActivity)mContext).showCustomDialog();
In your YourActivity.java
public void showCustomDialog(){
    Intent add = new Intent(MyActivity.context,MySecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(add);
}
```

In your activity handle your result and make changes in dialog.

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and override `onActivityResult` callback to get result.

**Note**

- To get the result in your fragment make sure you call `startActivityForResult(intent,reqCode)` instead of `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,reqCode)` in your fragment.
- If the hosting activity already overrides the `onActivityResult`, make sure it calls `super.onActivityResult` for unhandled result codes.